# Nessus 6.7.0 global.db file growing exponentially

Tags: nessus

We upgraded from Nessus 5.x to 6.7. Our old global.db file was only ~300kb consistently before the upgrade. Since we upgraded, it has grown exponentially to a couple of GB in only a month. Has anyone else also encountered this and found a solution?

Comment: Just checked the one on our scanner (used weekly) it's about 373K.